# Splitting a string into a list

Tags: python

I want to split a string into a list.
I have been trying this

```
r='ABCD'

a=r.split()
['ABCD']
```

I want something like this 
['A','B','C','D']

I do not want to use any for loop for this.
Is there an in built programming construct to do so ?

Comment: In reality, you probably don't need to convert the string to a list at all. It's already a sequence, so you can index, slice or iterate over it etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string is a sequence, so just turn it into a list:

```
a = list(r)
```

Demo:

```
>>> r='ABCD'
>>> list(r)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Answer (score 1):

The default for spliting a string into a list is a space.  If your string was spaced, and in `split(' ')` it will spit when it sees a space and add each letter to the list individually.

Answer (score 0):

You should also learn to use list comprehensions as way of doing this since they are very fast and useful when you want to modify the items in some way:

```
>>> [item for item in 'ABCD']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

>>> [item for item in 'ABCDEFG' if item in 'AEIOU']
['A', 'E']
```